# Error in maven :No plugin found for the prefix 'get'

Tags: maven, glassfish, maven-3

I am running the following command for my project to run

```
mvn gwt:run >> D:\client.log 2>&1
```

It is giving me the following error:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'get' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\name.m2\repository), nexus (https://nexus.companyname.com/nexus/content/groups/public/)] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'get' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\RahulJ.m2\repository), nexus (https://nexus.companyname.com/nexus/content/groups/public/)]
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:94)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:262)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:222)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the command you wrote is not binded to the logs you provided.

The error `No plugin found for prefix 'get' in the current project and in the plugin groups`  means that you didn't declared get plugin in build section.

I think you tried `mvn get:run` and not `mvn gxt:run` ... didn't you mixed E and W letters (on your QWERTY keyboard ? ;)

Comment: If you disagree, please let a comment in order to improve my answer !